# TeamCity FTP Publish

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild, teamcity

I am trying to build and deploy my project in team city. I get green but it does not publish project to FTP. What could be the problem?

**Teamcity Build Step:**

[image]
**Publish Profile:**
[image]

**Buildlog of Teamcity:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try the **build step** `Visual Studio.sln`, give the **Solution file path** , select the **Visual Studio Version**, select the Target as `build;publish`, select **Configuration** as `release`. Then run the program. You will get an error message. Then check the following link for a solution.

http://www.jayway.com/2011/03/20/configuring-automatic-deployment-of-a-windows-azure-application-using-teamcity/

I hope this would help you.